# Getting on mediawiki spammers list?

Tags: mediawiki, spam, spamming

I am setting up a test site which I WANT to get spammed by WIKI spammers, ie those spambots that run rampant on a wiki site filling it up with junk data... How do i get on one of those lists?

Comment: Haha. I was just considering this as well.

Just out of curiosity. What is your motivation?

Comment: There are some forums where lists of wikis are or were traded, just look for these.

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to use your mediawiki install as a [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29)? Just allow anonymous changes to your wiki and the spammers will find you...